# will the property in the parent object changed after modified of the child object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

In the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2ifWcnQs6M)(around 46:30 ) **Douglas** give a example of object inheritance:

`myNewObject` was inherited from `myOldObject`
[image]

and if modified `myNewObject.name`, in the slide the `myOldObject.name` will not change.
[image]

But I tried it myself with following snippet:

```
<script>
    var a = {name:"John",age:5}
    var b = Object(a)
    b.name = "Ted"
    b.age = 6

    console.log(a)
    console.log(b)
</script>
```

And the output shows that not only `a.name` and `a.age` changed, but also `b.name` and `b.age`:

[image]

Was **Douglas** wrong about this? or is there anything I miss? cause if He was wrong, it's a huge mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are not inheriting the object.
[Check out MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance)

```
  var a = {name:"John",age:5};
  var b={};
  b.prototype= Object(a.prototype);
  b.name = "Ted";
  b.age = 6;

  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
```

http://jsbin.com/rudigazofa/1/watch?html,js,console

Comment: But this was not the way Douglas demonstrated in the video.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var a = {
   name: "John",
   age: 5
 }
 var b = Object.create(a)
 b.name = "Ted"
 b.age = 6

 console.log(a)
 console.log(b)
```

Just use `Object.create` instead of `object()` method.